# Something weird happening with strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, debugging, linked-list

Before I begin, I should preface this with the fact that I'm a student, and this is for an assignment. I need help understanding what's going wrong and how to fix it, but I don't want code segments telling me what to do.

So, I'm trying to solve a 16 tile puzzle. I'm using iterative deepening to find an optimal solution, and I'm testing a nextConfigs method to find the places the puzzle as is can move to.

```
private static LinkedList<Puzzle> nextConfigs(Puzzle start) {
    LinkedList<Puzzle> nextPuzzles = new LinkedList<Puzzle>();
    Puzzle wlast = start; //creates a copy of 'last'(start) for working with to get up
    //System.out.println("Debug 1");
    if(wlast.hasUp()){
        wlast.moveUp();
        nextPuzzles.add(wlast);
        System.out.println("Debug 11 " + wlast.toString());
        wlast = start; //resets working copy
    }
    if(wlast.hasRight()){
        wlast.moveRight();
        nextPuzzles.add(wlast);
        System.out.println("Debug 12 " + wlast.toString());
        wlast = start; //resets working copy
    }
    if(wlast.hasDown()){
        wlast.moveDown();
        nextPuzzles.add(wlast);
        System.out.println("Debug 13 " + wlast.toString());
        wlast = start; //resets working copy
    }
    if(wlast.hasLeft()){
        wlast.moveLeft();
        nextPuzzles.add(wlast);
        System.out.println("Debug 14 " + wlast.toString());
        wlast = start; //resets working copy
    }
    System.out.println("Debug 7: next configs contains: " + nextPuzzles.toString());
    for(Puzzle next: nextPuzzles){
        System.out.println("Debug 7.2 next configs contains " + next.toString());
    }
    return nextPuzzles;
}
```

The problem is, it's returning some odd values. using a test puzzle _aaabbbbccccdddd, it prints the following to the console (which I'm using to help debug);

```
Debug 12 a_aabbbbccccdddd
Debug 13 abaab_bbccccdddd
Debug 14 abaa_bbbccccdddd
Debug 7: next configs contains: [abaa_bbbccccdddd, abaa_bbbccccdddd, abaa_bbbccccdddd]
Debug 7.2 next configs contains abaa_bbbccccdddd
Debug 7.2 next configs contains abaa_bbbccccdddd
Debug 7.2 next configs contains abaa_bbbccccdddd
```

The Puzzle class holds a string containing the puzzle state, and an array of char's to edit (created by the toCharArray method). hasUp etc check if moving in a given direction is valid, and move Up etc do so, by editing the array and then setting the string equal to a new string created from the array (puzzle = new String(wpuzzle)). I'm running out of ideas for how to solve this one.

If anyone can see anything I've done wrong, or offer suggestions for what might be causing this, I'd appreciate it. I've tested the hasUp etc and Moveup etc methods to make sure that they work, and they do.

Comment: I don't understand much, but `Puzzle wlast = start; //creates a copy of 'last'(start) for working with to get up` is wrong. That doesn't create a copy. It just makes wlast reference the same object as start. So modifying the object referenced by wlast will also modify the object referenced by start, since these in fact constitute a unique object. You're always storing the same unique object in the list, and modifying it constantly.

Comment: Dud you step through the code in the debugger? (not just printing stuff out).  Learning how to use a debugger is a critical skill.

Comment: I did go through it in the debugger, which is how I know the hasUp etc methods work.  As for puzzle wlast = start being wrong...I didn't know that. Thanks. That's probably what I'm doing wrong. EDIT: Yup, that was the issue. I've fixed it now, thanks a bunch for pointing that out. Time to go do more testing.